# Update Sencha Architect project from Sencha Touch v2.0.x to Sencha Touch 2.1.x

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a project based on **Sencha Touch v2.0.x**, I was working on it in **Sencha Architect 2.0**. Now I have updated **Sencha Architect** to **2.1** and want to update my project to use **Sencha Touch 2.1.x**. How can I do that? Is there some kind of converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sencha Architect, open your Project Inspector. Then under Resources right click on Library and choose "Upgrade to Sencha Touch 2.1.x".

[image]

Comment: [link](http://senchatouchexp.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/sencha-touch-20x-upgrade-21.html) describes the process using Sencha Cmd - although this method is optional towards the described end result.